# How to set caption to a specific div class

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

The plugin i am using is: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

I was wondering if there is a way to set the caption to something other than the title of the image. I would like to get the caption from a specific tag/class.

My structure is such:

```
<a class="image-link" href="path.jpg">
<img src="path.jpg">
<p>Want this as caption</p>
</a>
```

I presume it is "titleSrc: 'title'," parameter but i dont know how to select the p tag for the caption (A class or id could attached if needed).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
titleSrc: function(item){
    return item.el.find('p').text()
}
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunatly it doesnt seem to work. My markup is `<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'image',
  closeOnContentClick:'true',
  mainClass: 'entry',
titleSrc: function(item){
    return item.el.find('p').text()
}
});
});
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you are using a single pop-up (one image, not a gallery). So you have to 'request' for the caption just once, - after opening a pop-up (in gallery you would need to get the text each time the image/other content changes).  Firstly, let's look into documentation and find out how to define callbacks:   [link 1](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api)

> You can define callbacks in callbacks option. Besides that, all Magnific Popup events are also dispatched using triggerHandler on target element (or to document if the element doesn’t exist).

```
$('.image-link').magnificPopup({
  // you may add other options here, e.g.:
  preloader: true,

  callbacks: {
    open: function() {
      // Will fire when this exact popup is opened
      // this - is Magnific Popup object
    },
    close: function() {
      // Will fire when popup is closed
    }
    // e.t.c.
  }
});
```

Looks like 'open' callback is just what we need. You also can run through the whole list, - might be useful in future.

Our next step I will divide into 3 smaller:

1. Get the element you clicked after opening a pop-up.
2. Find the paragraph inside it and get the text it contains.
3. Append this text into desired element in opened pop-up.

Let's take a look into next part of documentation, - Public properties.

```
magnificPopup.st.el // Target clicked element that opened 
                    //popup (works if popup is initialized from DOM element)
```

This will return

```
<a class="image-link" href="path.jpg">
<img src="path.jpg">
<p>Want this as caption</p>
</a>
```

so we can get the text of paragraph like this

```
magnificPopup.st.el.find('p')
```

or, without defining magnificPopup variable,

```
this.st.el.find('p')
```

Now you should choose an element where to add this text. I didn't see that you changed the standard markup (and you surely can do this if you want, - for example when build-in markup is not enough and you need to add extra elements, - you can find some info in documentation), so I can propose to add the caption at the top of the image, into `<div class="mfp-header"></div>`. Here another public property comes to help:

```
magnificPopup.content // direct reference to jQuery DOM element 
                      //that you open in popup
```

Now Lets improve our code:

```
callbacks: {
    open: function() {
        // store the text in imgCaption variable, - if you will need this later on
        var imgCaption =  this.st.el.find('p');  
        // append the text to the element 
        this.content.find('.mfp-header').html(imgCaption); 
     }     
 }
```

So, the whole your script should look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
     $('.image-link').magnificPopup({ 
          type:'image', 
          closeOnContentClick:'true', 
          mainClass: 'entry', 
          image: {
               titleSrc: function(item) { 
                   return item.el.attr('title') 
          // Actually, you don't need it now, because the text of paragraph 
          // plays the title role, but if you need both things, for example
          // 'title' for title and <p> for description, you can leave this method
               } 
          },
          callbacks: {
               open: function() {
                   var imgCaption =  this.st.el.find('p');  
                   this.content.find('.mfp-header').html(imgCaption); 
               }     
          }
      }); 
 });
```

Hope you get the idea. Feel free to ask any questions, will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `titleSrc` must be specified **within** the HTML as an **attribute**

For example:

```
<img src="path.jpg" title="Image Title">
```

For this, your jQuery would be:

```
image: { titleSrc: 'title' }
```

You can also use `data-title` instead of `title`.
You can add even more parameters on top of that, using other `data-` attributes - like a **caption**, .

For example:

```
<img src="path.jpg" title="Image Title" data-caption="Image Caption">
```

For this, your jQuery would be:

```
image: {
      titleSrc: function(item) {
          return item.el.attr('title') + item.el.attr('data-caption');
      }
}
```

You can also, add HTML styling elements to the function:

```
image: {
      titleSrc: function(item) {
          return '<strong>' + item.el.attr('title') + '</strong><br />' + item.el.attr('data-caption');
      }
}
```